# 2 csv file export to excel file using ssis

Tags: ssis

I'm trying read the data from 2 csv files and export into the new excel file, but I'm not able to export the data in excel destination. While doing the mapping of the columns, there are 4 columns in the input columns but it is showing only 1 column in available output column that is only F1. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please reply it asap....as i'm stuck with this issue from the past 2 days...thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are unable to map columns to a ‘new’ XL file.
If this is the case, the metadata for the mappings is probably the issue.

Try first creating a new xl file with the column headings and column types you want, then map to this.
Alternativly, right click on the excel destination and use the ‘Show Advanced Editor’ option and then adjust the columns in the ‘External Colums’ of ‘Input and Output settings tab.

You may then need to set the ValidateExternalMetadata option to false for the excel destination component in order to allow creation of new files from scratch.

Comment: Hi,Thanks its showing now the mapping columns,but what issue i'm now facing is after doing the data conversion it is still showing me the error while run the package.Error is:-[Excel Destination [772]] Error: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.
Please let me know how to solve this issue .Thanks in advnace

Comment: Yes...its working fine.i'm able to map the columns...thank so much

Answer (score 0):

Open an excel sheet and on the 1st row, give the column headings. Column A, B, C and D should have the same names as your source columns. After doing so, save the excel file and close the work book. Go to SSIS and open the Excel destination mappings. You should be able to map them now.

Comment: You can thank us by marking either one of the helpful replies as your answers.